# How I can trim seconds out of a time field in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, time

In my postgresql I have the following table:

```
Name: mytable
---
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
time TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE
```

And I select some info:

```
select id,time from mytable;
```

But I want the time to be formated without seconds. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to postgresql [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) you need to use the `to_char` function.

In your case you'll need to do:

1. For 12h formated time:

```sql
select id,to_char(time,'HH:MI') as time from mytable;
```

OR

```sql
select id,to_char(time,'HH:MI') as time from mytable;
```

2. For 24h format:

```
select id,to_char(time,'HH24:MI') as time from mytable;
```

This is applicable to all postgresql versions. I tested it on Postgresql 11.

Comment: Minor typo, use HH24 for the 24h format

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Dimitrios Desyllas , using "to_char" is the best way.

Alternatively, the same can also by achieved by "[date_trunc](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-date_trunc/)" function. It truncates the value to the nearest minute.

This can be done as:

```
SELECT id, date_trunc('minute', time) as new_time FROM mytable;
```

Another way of achieving this is by "Substring", this can be done as:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(time::text, 1, 2), ':', SUBSTRING(time::text, 4, 2)) as new_time FROM mytable;
```